# How to get an AppendBlobItem without creating or appending in Azure Java SDK

Tags: java, azure, azure-blob-storage

I need to get an existing AppendBlobItem using Azure Java SDK v12.
However, AppendBlobAsyncClient provide creating and appending a BlobItem methods, not simple get.

So I list BlobItems, like below, but BlobItem can't cast to AppendBlobItem.

```java
BlobContainerClientBuilder containerClientBuilder = new BlobContainerClientBuilder().endpoint(blobEndpoint).containerName(containerName)
                                                    .credential(new AzureSasCredential(sasCredential));
BlobContainerAsyncClient containerClient = containerClientBuilder.buildAsyncClient();
    
ListBlobsOptions listOption = new ListBlobsOptions();
listOption.setPrefix(blobPrefix);
    
// BlobItem can't cast to AppendBlobItem
BlobItem currentBlobItem =(AppendBlobItem)containerClient.listBlobs(listOption).sort(Comparator.comparing(BlobItem::getName)).blockFirst();
```

Is there a way to get an AppendBlobItem without creating or adding? or to convert BlobItem to AppendBlobItem.

Comment: Any update on this question?:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No,  ‘[AppendBlobItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/com.azure.storage.blob.models.appendblobitem?view=azure-java-stable)’ and ‘[BlobItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/com.azure.storage.blob.models.blobitem?view=azure-java-stable)’ are both directly Inherited from ‘java.lang.Object’.

They are actually no relation between them.

And you can check the above doc, 'BlobItem' doesn't have a method to convert to 'AppendBlobItem'.

So the answer is no.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
Instead of getting the AppendBlobitem, I will store the one that I appended.